# unable to uninstall netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: uninstallation, netbeans-8

Error message showing is :

> The specified target component - nb-base/8.0.1.0.201408251540 was not
>   found in the registry. The installer can continue as if the target
>   component was specified. Click yes to continue, No to exit the
>   installer.

I have tried a lot to uninstall my NetBeans8.0.2 but were unable. After lot of googling found out a solution. I think I should have and entry in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 31):

Best way to remove Netbeans can be done using following steps

1. Remove the **Netbeans** folder from program file
2. Delete the **.nbi**(hidden) folder from your C:\User{Current User}
3. Go to control panel and remove it

It works for me hope it will you too!

Comment: I tried this option in Windows 10 but alas the problem persisted

Comment: Comment 1 and 2 of the following link worked for me https://superuser.com/questions/595518/cannot-uninstall-netbeans-7-3-on-windows-8

Comment: Delete this folder too **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Netbeans**

Comment: Adding to @SureshKumar, delete also this folder: **C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans**

Answer (score 5):

Actually Devashish's answer is (partly) correct. If you click link provided by him, you will see that the problem (most likely) is because the install was done by a different user than the user who is uninstalling. (In my case, I added an admin user after the Netbeans install, so all computer changes now pass through the admin user)

Here is what I did to complete the install:

1. Find a **.nbi** folder under `C:\Users\folder`. This **folder** has **.nbi** folder under it
2. Open a command prompt and Go to NetBeans folder which has `uninstall.exe`
3. Run this command in the command prompt:

   `uninstall.exe --userdir c:\Users\folder\\.nbi`

**folder** is the folder you found in step 1.

This uninstalled for me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: For Step 2. I opened Windows PowerShell and entered command: ```cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.0.2'```. Running step 3 the uninstaller finally worked this time as expected without the error and doing everything - I didn't have to delete any folders. Thanks Rsc Rsc!

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
2. Delete "lock" file
3. Uninstall NetBeans

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the link to have a solution:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251943

The [comment 5](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251943#c5) has easiest solution:
Run Command Prompt in Administrator mode and run the following command :

> uninstall.exe --userdir c:\Users\Administrator.nbi

Comment: I tried this solution as follows: C:\Netbeans\NetBeans 8.0.2>uninstall.exe --userdir C:\Users\mark.burl\.nbi it launched the uninstall but popped up with the same problem

Comment: you need to use the username who installed netbean in your command argument

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to work in my Win 10 environment. I've also tried

```
.\uninstall.exe --userdir c:\Users\Administrator\.nbi
.\uninstall.exe --userdir c:\Users\Administrator.nbi
'NetBeans 8.0.1'\uninstall.exe --userdir c:\Users\eric_2\.nbi
.\'NetBeans 8.0.1'\uninstall.exe --userdir c:\Users\eric_2\.nbi
.\'NetBeans 8.0.1'\uninstall.exe --userdir c:\Users\eric_2.nbi
```

You get the point. I'm running the WindowsPowerShell as an Administrator.

Someone here must have successfully deleted it even with the error message from the OP. I just have to find out who!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

After struggling here and there, I:

1. Opened *c:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\lock* where XXX was the user name. Then, I renamed *lock*. (The name didn't matter.)
2. Then, I went back and uninstalled NetBeans.

By the way, I had to delete Java separately.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem as above.

Prior to the "symptoms", I installed the application in a newly created folder on the C drive (Not the Program Files default installation directory).

I then changed the name of the folder directory where the executable was installed to enable a third-party script to launch the NetBeans executable as the script required no spaces in the path. In any case, in attempting to uninstall the application again, I got the above error.

I tried running the command as outlined above (namely) running the command prompt with the following:

C:\Netbeans\NetBeans 8.0.2>uninstall.exe --userdir C:\Users\mark.burl.nbi

it launched the uninstall but the same error popped up.

I then undertook the following and the problem was solved for me:

1. I **manually** deleted the **NetBeans executable folder**.
2. I then **reinstalled** NetBeans to the **default Program Files location**.
3. I then **uninstalled** **NetBeans** **again** no problem.

Answer (score 0):

From PowerShell as administrator I removed all directories here described and finally enter regedit and search for all occurrences of “NetBeans (x86)”.  And delete all of them then restart and after that everything is clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Go to C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
2. Delete the folder named after your Netbean version you want to uninstall
3. Uninstall NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the reason. i.e while installing NetBeans i used our IT Team Admin credentials (assume user-1 ). But i am uninstalling with my credentials(assume user-2).
So, you can't uninstall. Follow below steps.

1.Go to **C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1>** you will find **uninstall.exe** file.
2.Find who is installed your netbeans for me user-1 (Admin).(You can find all users here C:\Users )
3.Then search for **.nbi** folder you can get at **C:\Users\{user-1}\.nbi** 
 Note: here user-1 is who installed your NetBeans initially.

finally open cmd prompt and run the command below given.

***C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1>uninstall.exe --userdir C:\Users\{user-1}\.nbi*** 
referred from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387962/10971996

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and no matter how hard I tried it won't uninstall until **I installed it all over again then uninstalled**.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I believe it is due to the fact that the application was installed under a different, local administrator in preparation for a gold image scenario. The missing component is likely holed up in that user's .nbi folder or in it's section of the registry.

My solution was to delete the folders under `C:\Program Files`. This included `Apache Software Foundation` for `Tomcat`; `glassfish-4.1.1`; and `Netbeans-8.2` (Everything was installed since no one ever knows what a dev is going to need).

I then ran the installer as myself. After that I ran the uninstaller and everything went smoothly.

The only issue I encountered is that the `Netbeans` entry in `Apps & features` wouldn't go away. I was able to get rid of it by opening `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` and running the uninstall option there as well. I got the notice that it could not be found because it might have already been uninstalled and did I want to remove the entry. I clicked `Yes`. It disappeared immediately from both interfaces.

No need for registry editing. Let whatever is left behind there be unless it is causing problems.

Answer (score -1):

Stop/ pause protection for your anti-virus. Then click on un-install. It will work for sure.